# Mobile Development Distribution

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, windows-mobile, mobile

Ok I have a question for the mobile developers out there.

Is there any other way to distribute and have people download your apps with out going through the manufacturers website store ( `iPhone , windows 7 phone store , android store etc` ) .

I don't feel like paying `Microsoft $100` a year to distribute apps I plan on giving out for free

Comment: You should change the subject line to be more indicative of what you are asking.

Comment: For Android, this has been asked a few times. Search for something like "android alternate markets" or something. It would be nice to have all the answers in one place though for all the major mobile platforms so I think this is a worthy question.

Comment: @MatrixFrog I agree, it's a worthy question, but the original subject line just had to be changed.  The OP changed it to a much more appropriate title.  Not all of us search by tag.  Sometimes I just troll through the top questions when I'm bored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most android phones (with the exception of some current AT&T models) can have an option enabled in their settings menu to permit installation of applications from 3rd party websites, email attachments, etc.  As far as I have heard, all current android phones (included the restricted AT&T models) can have USB debugging enabled which will permit applications to be installed by means of the software development kit (free).  There's also a 3rd-party tool called the "sideload wonder machine" that permits windows PC's to leverage this installation mechanism without needing to install the actual SDK on the PC.

Comment: The SDK/Sideload Wonder Machine approach will work on all devices that have the Android Market installed and some that do not, since all Market-compatible devices must support installing apps via USB.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this for iPhone, as apps have to have a certificate and provisioning profile if you like to not install it through the app store.
In android (as previous posts have said) it's easier possible.

I like to raise the question and concern why you actually would want to do this.

1. If your app is soo inconvenient to install, most users will simply not do it. My parents don't even know what a apk is, so don't expect them to have set all these params.
2. If you don't like to pay the minimal fee (125usd for both android and apple), you really might want to consider the purpose of your app.
3. Consider a ad supported version to cover the costs
4. Yesterday I read that per day (!) around 300000 new android phones getting activated. I simply don't see the reason why anyone (except big companies with lots of infrastructure) should host anything related to app distribution, as it easily becomes heavy load on your server).

Comment: +1 for pointing out the gigantic scale of app deployment these days when practically everyone has a smart phone in their hand.  It's best to just leave it up to the companies with the infrastructure explicitly designed to handle the traffic, security, and maintenance of the service.

Comment: That makes sense for a business with a budget, how about a broke indipendent developer open source supporting college student?

Comment: @jchase If you are giving out source - since it's open source - have you considered something like google project or one of the other online svn or git sites available?  They will host for free and you can distribute your app and source and not have to pay a dime.  Of course, that assumes a developer audience.

Comment: I really don't want to get political, but android makes it easy for everyone to generate small revenue. See the 25 bucks as a investment you need to get and having an ROI is your top goal once you start. We unluckily cannot change the reality of these "markets", or "stores".

Comment: Well Android is the only one with a reasonable price. I will be paying that , 25 bucks ain't bad. I will be avoiding iPhone & WP7 though lol   and no I haven't checked into a svn or anything I will thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Android allows you to distribute apps without a marketplace I believe.  Android marketplace is 25$ lifetime.

Comment: android marketplace is 25$ lifetime. Apple is 99$/year

Comment: Yea i saw android seemed the least ridiculous , but paying ANYTHING for something I'm already losing profit on doesn't make sense . How can open source developers be expected to pay for doing free work?

Comment: @pastjean I stand corrected.  I still haven't felt my app is ready for the market place as I want to make sure I get maximum buzz so I haven't delved too deep.  I do know that developers offer libraries and other apps you can download and buy using the barcode scanner app.  That's why I figured that you can purchase apps outside of the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

BlackBerry applications can be distributed online without going through RIM.  Note however, that some OS API calls require code to be 'signed' with BlackBerry signing keys.  These cost $20, and have *practically* unlimited use.

Comment: Looks like I'll be releasing my projects on Android and BlackBerry lol

Comment: Have fair warning, BlackBerry applications are not trivial.  Developing UI is a very involved process.

Comment: Well I'm not on a deadline so I got plenty of time to learn lol